# How to access runtime controls from another form? (C#)

Tags: c#, forms, modifiers

I have a form (Form1) and a button on it. When I press that button, I create runtime panels stored in an array of panels, declared like that:

```
 Panel[] Panouri_variabile = new Panel[20];
```

If I press the button, a panel is created. If I press the button again, another panel is created underneath the previous panel and so on.

Each panel has a textbox inside it. Obviously, the textboxes are stored in an array of textboxes, declared like that:

```
 TextBox[] Nume_variabila = new TextBox[20];
```

The user writes something in each textbox of each panel.

Now, I want to access the data written by the user in those textboxes, **from another form**, like that:

```
 Form1 form = new Form1();
 form.Panouri_variabile[i].Nume_variabila[i].Text
```

That could be easily done if the panels and the texboxes are created at *design-time*, by simply setting the *Modifier* property of all controls to *public*.

The problem is that they are created at run-time, so I can't change the *Modifier* property.

After a lot of searches I found the following posible solution:

```
 Panel new_Panel = Panouri_variabile[i];
```

And then declare the following property at the same level as the event - handlers are (class-level I think)

```
 public Panel new_Panel { get; private set; }
```

I noticed that I can see the new_Panel from another form, so I can access it like that:

```
 Form1 form = new Form();
 form.new_Panel
```

but the problem that it is not indexable! I have an array of panels (and an array of texboxes) so I should access them using an *index*, as I specified above!

Is there a way of accessing those texboxes from another form? Or should I create them design-time?

Comment: So declare your property as an array instead.

Comment: I replaced Panel[] Panouri_variabile = new Panel[20]; by public Panel[] Panouri_variabile = new Panel[20];  It works! I can see the array with form.Panouri_variabile[i] (so it is indexable). In the same way I "managed" to access the texboxes. The problem is that when I try to access one, like: form.Nume_variabile[i].Text, it gives me a null reference exception. Why is that? I almost found what I was searching for and it doesn't work!

Comment: @SLaks: you mean something like: public Panel[] new_Panel { get; private set; } that? Allright, but how can I access the texboxes from another form?